# error creating bean: No qualifying bean, expected single matching bean but found 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, autowired

I have a query in Spring MVC
I have 4 DAO(data access object) classes for DB related methods
3 of them are child classes and 4th one is parent of all. Say A,B,C,D are 4 classes, A is parent of B,C,D
So I annotated all these as **@Repository**. Now in another class lets say E , i am **Autowiring** B class as:

```
Class E {
@Autowired 
B b;
..
..
}
```

This works fine.
Now in another class F, I am doing :

```
Class F {
@Autowired 
A a;
..
..
}
```

Now executing this gives error:

> **No qualifying bean, expected single matching bean but found 3**

Now I understood the problem but still not very clear to which basic spring concept this is using which i am missing. Can someone explain in detail.
I think i am missing **@Qualifier** on top of A class. But this A class is not an interface. So what if i need specifically the methods of A class which are not present in child classes. Then how will qualifier help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring by default uses Type of the bean to find a match for autowiring.  If more that one bean of the same Type is found in the ApplicationContext, then  you'll get an error "expected single matching bean but found 3, A, B, C" .  One way to find match using the @Qualifier which finds a Bean by its name.

```
@Component class A implements DAO {...}
@Component class B implements DAO {...}

class F {
@Autowired
@Qualifier('a') //lowercase "a" will be the default bean name for A
A a;
```

Another option is to mark @Primary class A then bean A will be autowired and you can omit @Qualifier

Comment: hey thanks , what you pointed out was being missed by me. But i would like to add that this multiple bean found will be thrown when we try to autowire the parent class and not the child class. I tried this. If we autowire child class it doesnt throw error